# Intercept file request in ASP.NET and return dynamically created content instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm using a javascript framework that can only draw simple graphics objects or take a url to an image file. I need more complex graphics but there are too many combinations to create all the different possible images. Is it possible to intercept a file request at the server and return dynamically created content (png image) in its place ?

Comment: Yes, take a look at handlers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c67a8bd(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can have a controller action return an image file.  Here's an example of one that I wrote to write text to an image and return it.

Note that you probably want to use an `OutputCache` and use `VaryByParam` so that the output cache knows what query string parameters should be considered to decide if a request is for an image that was already generated or not.

```
[OutputCache(Duration=86400, VaryByParam="text;maxWidth;maxHeight")]
public ActionResult RotatedImage(string text, int? maxWidth, int? maxHeight)
{
    SizeF textSize = text.MeasureString(textFont);

    int width = (maxWidth.HasValue ? Math.Min(maxWidth.Value, (int)textSize.Width) : (int)textSize.Width);
    int height = (maxHeight.HasValue ? Math.Min(maxHeight.Value, (int)textSize.Height) : (int)textSize.Height);

    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
            g.DrawString(text, textFont, Brushes.Black, zeroPoint, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

            bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png");
            }
        }
    }
}
```